# Angular 5 APP_INITIALIZER: Provider parse error: Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using the `APP_INITIALIZER` token to do something on page load before my Angular app is bootstrapped. The service I am using for that logic depends on another service I have in my `CoreModule`.

I know this error is happening because of the fact that I'm injecting the `AuthService` into my `AppService`, however I can't see why that should matter. `AuthService` does not inject `AppService`, so how is it a circular dependency?

This is my error:

```
> Uncaught Error: Provider parse errors: Cannot instantiate cyclic
> dependency! ApplicationRef ("[ERROR ->]"): in NgModule AppModule in
> ./AppModule@-1:-1 Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! ApplicationRef
> ("[ERROR ->]"): in NgModule AppModule in ./AppModule@-1:-1
>     at NgModuleProviderAnalyzer.parse (compiler.js:19550)
>     at NgModuleCompiler.compile (compiler.js:20139)
>     at JitCompiler._compileModule (compiler.js:34437)
>     at eval (compiler.js:34368)
>     at Object.then (compiler.js:474)
>     at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:34366)
>     at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (compiler.js:34260)
>     at CompilerImpl.compileModuleAsync (platform-browser-dynamic.js:239)
>     at PlatformRef.bootstrapModule (core.js:5567)
>     at bootstrap (main.ts:13)
```

Here is my `AppModule`:

```
import { NgModule, APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';

import { AppService, AppServiceFactory } from './app.service';
import { CoreModule } from 'core';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        // ...
        CoreModule,
        // ...
    ],
    providers: [
        AppService,
        {
            provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
            useFactory: AppServiceFactory,
            deps: [AppService],
            multi: true
        }
    ],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Here is the `AppService`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { AuthService } from 'core/services/auth/auth.service';

export function AppServiceFactory(appService: AppService): () => Promise<any> {
    return () => appService.doBeforeBootstrap();
}

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
    constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

    doBeforeBootstrap(): Promise<any> {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            this.authService.isLoggedIn().then((loggedIn: boolean) => {
                // If the user is logged in, resolve (do nothing).
                if (loggedIn) {
                    return resolve();
                }

                // Otherwise, refresh the users token before resolving.
                this.authService.refreshToken().pipe(
                    finalize(() => resolve())
                ).subscribe();
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Anyone know why such an error occurs?

**Edit** (dependencies of `AuthService`):

```
constructor(
    private ref: ApplicationRef,
    private router: Router,
    private http: HttpClient,
    // Other custom services that are NOT imported into AppService...
) {}
```

Comment: Are you providing the `AuthService` somewhere? I see the `AppService` is. Not sure if that not being provided would cause your issue.

Comment: It is provided in the `CoreModule`, which is imported in the `AppModule` in the example above.

Comment: What are the dependencies of AuthService ?

Comment: @NoémiSalaün Edited question.

Comment: I don't know exactly how it works internally, but maybe the ApplicationRef does not exist before bootstraping the app, and that's why it cannot works, because you try to instantiate the AuthService before the bootstrap

Comment: @NoémiSalaün That's a brilliant idea, however no luck. I could see how that may cause this, though. I thought it might be because `AuthService` is not in the injector yet since the app hasn't been bootstrapped, however I'd expect an error more along the lines of trying to access properties of an undefined variable as opposed to a circular dependency...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You provide `APP_INITIALIZER` with a factory that depends on `AppService` that depends on `AuthService` that depends on `ApplicationRef` that depends on `ApplicationInitStatus` that depends on `APP_INITIALIZER`... et voila

See https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5.2.9/packages/core/src/application_init.ts and https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5.2.9/packages/core/src/application_ref.ts at line 398

Comment: Beautiful work, thanks sir. Time to create a proxy service to import into both `AuthService` and `AppService` so the circular dependency can go away.

Comment: If a service need some dependencies that can be resolve after the bootstrap, you can inject the Injector, and then get the real dependency later when the app is bootstraped